# Check best answer with the most views

Tags: discussion, feature-request, views

Is there a way to see which of one of a user's answers reached the most people? I know this is possible for questions, since a user's questions can be ordered based on their view count, however, I was wondering if the same can be done for answers.

Can they be ordered based on the number of views of the question to which the answer pertains?

If not, do you think this would be an interesting feature to implement? What would be the drawbacks of such a feature?

Comment: The view count on a question will include views that occurred before the answer was posted.

Comment: I would like a sort by views. However, "this isn't a popularity contest" is the historical argument against allow a views sort - coupled with the fact that the actual view counter involves some calculation that makes it slightly harder to sort on.

Comment: I envision many rounding and logic bugs, as well as dev headaches. I do not, however, envision a great benefit coming from this.

Comment: "people reached" exists purely for marketing purposes.  We should be giving it less attention, not more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps this answers an aspect of your quest. I just wrote the following `SEDE` query a few minutes ago, and verified quickly the results:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/405009/questions-i-have-answered-sorted-by-question-view-count

Enter your UserId. `4333347` for you.

It shows the top 100 view count questions that you have answered.

Raw query:

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

select top 100 someQuestion.Id as [Post Link],
someQuestion.ViewCount,
someQuestion.CommentCount as comms,
someQuestion.AnswerCount,
someQuestion.FavoriteCount as favs,
yourAnswer.Score as YourScore,
someQuestion.Tags
from Posts yourAnswer 
join Posts someQuestion
on yourAnswer.ParentID=someQuestion.Id 
where yourAnswer.OwnerUserId=@UserId
order by ViewCount desc
```

The counts may be off slightly from visible content, such as whether or not you can see deleted answers.

Also note that the SEDE data gets refreshed about once a week. So, to the best of my knowledge, though the stats may be a little stale, when you click off the link, you are back on real-time data in the actual *live* Q&A page.

Comment: you could extend it further of course. One of the first things to do could be to add a `yourAnswer.Score` column. Net score. Which I just did, next to the tags column.